# List Array Objects and their Variables to the Main method

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

Alright folks, I am new here but have used the site on countless different occasions in trying to find a solution to the problem I have. I have an automobile inventory program that I am working on for school. Essentially I use setters and getters to add Objects to an ArrayList in my Automobile Class.

I am having a lot of trouble writing the listAllVehicles method. At first I could list vehicles in the vehicles arraylist but it would give me a pointer to the object. So it looked something like this com.automobile@1662365. I want to create a loop method called listAllVehicles in the Automobile Class that loops through the array list and prints a short description of each vehicle until the list is done. I have made some headway writing the code but it isn't working and the for loop isn't initializing. I'm sure you guys will know what the heck I am doing wrong.

My code isn't set up currently to a ToString method for formatting what is printed, but I am open to the idea (already tried but couldn't figure it out)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

I have tried to cast to a String. I have messed around with casting to an object in the for loop. A bunch of different things really, but I can't seem to get this all to work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String model, make, color;
        int year = 0;
        int mileage = 0;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("[1]Add a Vehicle\n[2]List All 
        Vehicles\n[3]Update a Vehicle\n[4]Delete a Vehicle\n[5]Quit\n");
        System.out.print("Please choose from an option above: ");
        int userChoice = userInput.nextInt();
        switch(userChoice) {
        case 1:
            Scanner addVehicleScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Automobile newVehicle = new Automobile();
            System.out.print("What is the vehicle make: ");
            make = addVehicleScanner.next();
            newVehicle.setMake(make);
            System.out.print("What is the vehicle model: ");
            model = addVehicleScanner.next();
            newVehicle.setModel(model);
            System.out.print("What is the vehicle color: ");
            color = addVehicleScanner.next();
            newVehicle.setColor(color);
            System.out.print("What is the vehicle year: ");
            year = addVehicleScanner.nextInt();
            newVehicle.setYear(year);
            System.out.print("What is the vehicle mileage: ");
            mileage = addVehicleScanner.nextInt();
            newVehicle.setMileage(mileage);
            newVehicle.addVehicle(newVehicle);
            vehicleInventory.main(args);
            break;
        case 2:
            Automobile printAllVehicles = new Automobile();
            printAllVehicles.listAllVehicles();
            break;
        case 3:
            //FIX ME: Add Update Vehicle Code
            break;
        case 4:
            //FIX ME: Add Delete Vehicle Code
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("\n\nGoodbye!");
            break;




public void listAllVehicles() {
        Automobile temp = new Automobile();
        for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
            temp = (Automobile) vehicles.get(i);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few suggestions to make your code work

1) Override `toString` method of `Automobile` class and return a meaning full detail of automobile object so that when you call `System.out.println` on an object of `Automobile`, it gives you that details

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Automobile [ model "+ model +"]";
}
```

2) Never call `main` method like `vehicleInventory.main(args)`. Main method is to be call by JVM as a starting point of your class. In your code, instead of calling this, you can use `while` loop

Comment: You will have to forgive me. I am only a few weeks into learning Java. Where would I place this override code? I tried it a few days ago but wasn't implementing it correctly, or in the right place, Because I could't get it to work...

Comment: In `Automobile` class. Google how to override `toString` in a class. If you are using IDE, you will have shortcuts to write that method(For eclipse, it is Alt + Shift + S + S)

Comment: Alright well I created the override code. It is as follows.    


@Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Automobile [make=" + make + ", model=" + model + ", color=" + color + ", year=" + year + ", mileage="
    + mileage + "]";
 }

Comment: So how would I call this method from the main class to list all the vehicles. I assume a for loop, you mentioned a while loop. Again, very sorry, still learning...

Comment: When you print an object of `Automobile` class using `System.out.println`, like you did in `listAllVehicles` method, this method will be automatically called.

Comment: @ Ashishkumar Singh I understand that. But I need to initiate the method from the user Interface I created in the main method. So if the user selects option 2, then the method in the Automobile class should run and return the string for each object. I am never calling the main class from the automobile class, I am calling the listAllVehicles method from the Automobile class, but I am calling that method from the main class. Something is wrong in the main class, it isn't letting me call the listAllVehicle method I created. I will attach my current code.

Comment: public void listAllVehicles() {
  for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(vehicles.get(i));
  } 
 }


This is my Automobile Class I created that has the for loop and prints the vehicle in the element matching the value of i. From my understanding this should automatically call the over ride toString method and format that text.

Comment: case 2:
   break;

This is my current code in the main method where if the user selects option two, the code to call the listAllVehicles method should be written here. Eclipse keeps giving me errors with all of the different things I tried..

Comment: @lordleviticus Instead of updating the code in comment, kindly update the code in your question and also the error that eclipse is showing you